# Modifying ..count.. in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use a expression like that:

```
df <- data.frame(x=runif(1000),y=runif(1000),id=sample(1:2,1000,T,c(0.3,0.7)))
df %>%  
  group_by(id) %>%  
  mutate(n=n()) %>%  
  ggplot()+  
  geom_hex(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = ..count../n ))+
  facet_grid(id ~ .)
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'n' not found

Is there a way to modify the output of ..count..? 
In the example the output would be the same as with ..density.., but in the end i want to divide through other values, which arent the same as the length

Comment: Please make your example reproducible by providing code to make `df`.

Comment: what is that you are trying to show? the percentage contribution of a certain group?

Comment: i added df.
the contribution of a certain group, yes. Think of passes/90minutes of football players. So i want to show how many passes they play on average in a certain area. As some players played more minutes, i need to standardize it

Comment: If you count by `id`, wouldn't you get what you did with `mutate`?